# IWebBrowser2 Windows Mobile 6.5.3. Cannot Receive PostData

Tags: c++, atl, windows-mobile-6.5, iwebbrowser2, postdata

i have a problem in receiving PostData, using the IWebBrowser2 - Interface.

My Handler for the BeforeNavigate2-Event looks like this

```
void MyBrowser::OnBeforeNavigate2(

      IDispatch* pDisp,
      VARIANT* URL,
      VARIANT* pvtFlags,
      VARIANT* pvtTargetFrameName, 
      VARIANT* pvtPostData, 
      VARIANT* pvtHeaders,
      VARIANT_BOOL* pvbCancel) {

      // ...
}
```

If i watch the **pvtPostData** in the Debugger, after i sent some PostData, its **tagVARIANT::VARTYPE** contains the Value "VT_ERROR" and the **tagVARIANT::SAFEARRAY** is also emtpy.

Does anybody has an idea on how ro resolve this problem?

I think it is important to mention, that the same implementation ist working on Windows CE6, Windows CE7 and Windows Desktop (32Bit).

Thanks in advance.